# Sending server response when an events occurs but this cause a (cannot modify headers, headers have already been sent) error

Tags: node.js, express, events, routes, eventemitter

In my project the user makes a request to this route some complex logic happens and the app sends a response to the user when a move-made event occurs.
the code works fine the response is sent to the user but the app refuses to exit the route handler, this makes the server to crash with an error message of (cannot modify headers, headers have already been sent) when I tried to visit the route again

this is my code

```js
app.post('/api/play', (req, res) =>{

    gameStart.humanPlay(req.body)

    gameStart.on("move-made", (moves) => {

        res.send(moves)

    })
    
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the event listener inside the play route creates multiple event listeners each time the client send a post request to the play route, which sends multiple response to the client this is what caused the error message (cannot modify headers headers have already been sent).

#### To fix this error pass, res as a argument of humanPlay and delete the event listener from your play route

```js
app.post('/api/play', (req, res) =>{

    gameStart.humanPlay(req.body, res)

})
```

and send the respond from within the class

```js
res.send(this.moves)
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining why the res.send is appropriate in the humanPlay method, but is a problem in the event listener.